# Substring Query returning null

Tags: mysql, substring

I have this query where im returning a facebook profile link like this `https://www.facebook.com/profilename/`. Now i want that the first part of the link to not show up which is this `https://www.facebook.com/` so only the username is displayed but the query is displaying nothing.

**Query**

```
SELECT facebook_link FROM users WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(facebook_link, 'm/', -1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to manipuldate the selected data, the where clause does nothing to the column selected

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(facebook_link, 'com/', -1) as facebook_link 
FROM users
```

And to get rid of the trailing `/` try

```
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '/' FROM SUBSTRING_INDEX('https://www.facebook.com/profilename/', 'com/', -1))
FROM users
```